# Setting columns to references in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my web app, I have nodes and links.  A link has two nodes.  One node is a source node, and the other node is a target node.  Basically, I want source and target columns in the database that hold references to nodes.  I am trying to figure out how to implement this.

Here is the migration for the nodes model:

```
class CreateNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :nodes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :group
      t.references :link, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the node model:

```
class Nodes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :link
end
```

I am trying to figure out how to set up the migration for the links model.  Here is what I have so far:

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.integer :value
      t.boolean :checked

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what I have in my model:

```
class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :nodes
end
```

Would the correct migration look like this?

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.integer :value
      t.boolean :checked
      t.references :source
      t. references :target

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You only define `t.references ...` in the migration whose model has `belongs_to`.  So in this case `nodes` would have `references` defined and `links` would **not** have `references` defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.references :smith` is basically a shortcut for `t.integer :smth_id` so if your Nodes belong to Links, then yes that construction seems correct.

not sure where your `links#source` and `links#target` point to though.